# What is this “Can you help?” message above the answer box?

Tags: discussion, answers, sharing, share-this

I was looking at a new question on Retrocomputing ([Where and what was Haunt.bat? A game pre-loaded on a c1992 PC](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1985/621)) and saw this message above the answer box:

[image: Message]

What is this message?  Was it added by a mod?  I don't see it on any other question.  It looks like an alternative to the "Know someone who can answer?" message.  Is this an A/B test?  When was this added?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We're currently running an experiment with different versions of a call to action on questions.

The original version is

> Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email, Google+, Twitter, or Facebook.

The new copy being tested is

> Can you help? SiteName depends on everyone sharing their knowledge. If you're able to answer this question, please do!

The original is still shown to users on their own questions (since it's weird to prompt them to also *answer*) and people who aren't part of the experiment group.

Comment: I knew it had to be A/B testing!  Thanks Adam for clearing that up.

Comment: Was there some outcome from this experiment? Are there plans to change the text of the message? I have recently asked a related question here: [What happened to “depends on everyone sharing their knowledge” message? Can this be changed on per-site basis?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313962)

Answer (score 2):

This is probably to promote answering to raise the beta stats for questions answered and answer to question ratio.

As you can see, other beta sites have this to (Coffee Stack Exchange Beta is the one seen here):

[image]

Language Learning Stack Exchange Beta:

[image]

Retrocomputing Beta:

[image]

Since beta sites probably need lots of activities and very high and excellent sites for graduation. This also appears only on questions that currently don't have answers. This may also appear for inactive users since I am no longer that active at all in the above sites.

Comment: Right, but it doesn't appear on every question, and this is the first time I'm seeing it.  I've been a member of Retrocomputing since the public beta.  Is this new?

Comment: @JAL See my edit

Comment: Do you have a source for that?  Or are you just looking at unanswered questions.

Comment: @JAL Try https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/2550/what-is-phonics versus https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/2542/why-do-some-teach-biblical-hebrew-with-modern-verb-tenses

Comment: I don't have any sources though

Comment: Why does that message not appear on [this question](http://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1998/621)?

Comment: See my edit, I think you're mistaken

Comment: [Nope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2Sob.png)